# Getting information from an object selected using Mouse Listeners

Tags: java

So basically I am trying to make the Set card game the idea is to select 3 cards from a 4x3 board of cards determine if they are all a match or all opposite and display a message. I have build the cards and they all have a value for shade, shape, color, and number. What I am having trouble with is when I click on the card I am able to remove it. What I want to do is click on a card that is 2 red dashed squiggles and have it return 2,1,2,3 and add it onto a sum for each. Then after the three cards are selected determine if they are a match. I do not even know how to go about doing this. The only thing I have really tried was saving the card I clicked on to a new object.

```
package assignment3;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import acm.graphics.*;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class SetGame extends GraphicsProgram
{
    private int APP_WIDTH = 470;
    private int APP_HEIGHT = 300;
    GObject Card[][];

    public void run()
    {
        setSize(APP_WIDTH,APP_HEIGHT);

        for(int row = 0;row < 3; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                Card[][] setCard = new Card[4][3];
                setCard[col][row] = new Card(col*60, row*60, getRandomNum()+1,getRandomNum()+1,getRandomNum()+1,getRandomNum()+1);
                add(setCard[col][row]);
            }
            println();
        }
        addMouseListeners();
    }


    public int getPigment(int num)
    {
        int pigment = num;
        String[] color = new String[3];     
        color[0] = "red";
        color[1] = "green";
        color[2] = "purple";
        return pigment;     
    }

    //gets a random shape
    public int getShape(int num)
    {
        int shape = num;
        String[] Shape = new String[3];     
        Shape[0] = "circle";
        Shape[1] = "diamond";
        Shape[2] = "squiggle";
        return shape;           
    }

    public int getShade(int num)
    {
        int shade = num;
        String[] Shade = new String[3];     
        Shade[0] = "solid";
        Shade[1] = "dashed";
        Shade[2] = "hollow";
        return shade;
    }

    public int getRandomNum()
    {
        Random number = new Random();
        int num = number.nextInt(3);
        return num;
    }


    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        GObject whichCard = getElementAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if(whichCard == null)return;
        remove(whichCard);
    }

}
```

And here is the constructor on the other class

```
package assignment3;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Random;

import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import acm.graphics.*;

//Written by Dan Mattwig
//This program is built to display properties for cards

public class Card extends GCompound
{       
    private int color;
    private int shape;
    private int shading;
    private int number;


    public Card(int X,int Y,int color,int shape, int shading, int number)
    {
        setLocation(X,Y);
        this.color = color;
        this.shape = shape;
        this.shading = shading;
        this.number = number;
        int image = (color * 3) + (shape * 9) + (shading * 27) + (number - 39);
        GImage card = new GImage("images/"+image+".gif");
        add(card,X,Y);      
    }




}
```

Comment: We can only guess what you mean by "collect the values from the cards"; I know it is clear to you what you want, but it is not clear to people who want to help you but simply have no context in which to work. Try to imagine that we don't know anything about your program or what you want it to do, and explain it that way. Also tell us what you've tried; we do better explaining programming things that people have tried, rather than coming up with code to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When clicked, you're going to need to determine if the source of the event represents a `Card`, for example...

```
if (whichCard instanceof Card) {
    ...
}
```

You will then need to determine the properties of `Card`, but you've provided no means by which to do this.  You will need to provide a series of getters so you can obtain the information you need, for example...

```
public int getColor() {
    return color;
}

public int getShape() {
    return shape;
}

public int getShading() {
    return shading;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

At this point, you need to start making decisions.  You could add each `Card` to a `List` of some kind as it is clicked and process it at a later stage or make comparisons when they click, that's up to you.

At any rate, I be tempted to use the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface...

Comment: Thank you! Ill give it a shot. The idea is to try to update it as each card is clicked

Comment: You sir have helped out tremendously. Thank you.